# placement of break and return statements in python

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to write a function that returns the path of the first file found in a nest of folders. What I have so far is :

```
def dicom_name(rootDir):
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
        for f in fileList:
            print(dirName,f)
            return(os.path.join(dirName,f))
        break
```

Right now if I run this and then run

```
dcm=dicom_name("test_dir")
print(dcm)
```

I see "None"

I have tried different placements of the return and break statements.  What is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Running this locally for me does not raise a `SyntaxError`, are you sure you've pasted the complete code?

Comment: Look at the *full error message* - it will tell you the line number of the offending `return` statement, which is certainly not the `return` in the code fragment you posted, since it's clearly not outside of a function.

Comment: You don't need the outer loop at all; `dirName, subdirList, fileList = next(os.walk(rootDir))`.

Comment: Or the inner loop: `f = next(fileList)`. You would need to check if `fileList` is empty, though, or catch the resulting `StopIteration` exception.

Comment: I edited the question. Even without the syntax error, the function doesn't return the value I want it to.

Comment: Your code should be working. Are you sure that the "test_dir" your are giving as an argument is in the same directory with your .py file your are executing? Are you sure that it has files inside?

Comment: The test dir was in the same directory as the .py file I was executing, but I didn't realize I was executing it from a different directory. Feeding in the correct path dcm=dicom_name("../test_dir") worked!

Comment: See my edited answer below. You should remove the `break` to manage the case in which  `test_dir` has no file, but only subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your don't need the `break`. 
Your function is returning always after one execution of the outer thread, even if no file is found in that iteration.
Remove the `break`and it will work.

As an example, if you have just one file `test_dir/a/b.txt`, 
in the first run of the outer thread you have

```
dirName = test_dir 
subdirList = ['a'] 
fileList = []
```

and in the second run:

```
dirName = test_dir/a 
subdirList = [] 
fileList = ['b.txt']
```

so you want to continue until you find something in the `fileList` variable.

Comment: This was also helpful in solving my problem. The break statement was causing it to to return nothing. It works now.